# Sidebar change category background color on hover (jsFiddle)

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a sidebar for my website. When a user hovers over a category, a submenu opens up and when a user hovers over this submenu I would like the corresponding category background color to change. I created a jsfiddle to help illustrate my problem. I appreciate any help in this regard.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
$(".sidemenu").hover(function(){
    $("category").closest().parent().css("background-color","red");
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ahren/BGcDc/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just edited your CSS to change the parent `background colour` to `white`. The edited code is here:

```
$(".category").hover(function() {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(this).find(".submenu").show().parent().css('background', '#fff');
    $(this).find(".submenu li:eq(0)").css("border-top", "1px solid blue");
    $(this).find(".submenu li:last").css("border-bottom", "1px solid blue");
    $(this).find(".submenu li:first").css("border-left", "none");
    $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");
    $(this).css("width", "205px");
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid blue");
    $(this).css("border-top", "1px solid blue");
    $(this).css("border-right", "none");
});
$(".category:last").css("border-bottom", "1px solid grey");
$(".category").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#eee");
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid grey");
    $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");
    $(this).css("width", "180px");
    $(".category:last").css("border-bottom", "1px solid grey");
});
$(".submenu,#sidebar").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".category").css("width", "180px");
});​
```

Also find the CSS for the same below:

```
.category{text-decoration:none; border:1px solid grey; border-bottom:none; width:180px; padding:3px 8px 4px 30px; background-color:#eee;}
.submenu{list-style-type:none; background-color:#eee; width:200px; position:absolute; display:none; margin-left:189px; margin-top:-24px; box-shadow:4px 4px 9px #333;}
.submenu li{padding:3px 8px 4px 10px;  border-left:1px solid blue; border-right:1px solid blue; border-top:1px solid #bbb; border-bottom:none; margin-left:0px; background: #fff;}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
$(".submenu li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","yellow");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this `$(this).css('background-color','red');` in your `$(".category").hover();` function. Since you are using `$(this)` so many times you should try to cache it in a variable for best practice.